# Hydro turtlebot simulator bringup issues

Tags: gazebo, ros-hydro, kobuki, gazebo-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having problems getting the turtlebot simulator up and running in hydro. I installed ROS, gazebo, turtlebot_gazebo stacks and followed the instructions given [here](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator)

I am getting the following when I run `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_empty_world.launch`

```
... logging to /home/prasanna/.ros/log/5f52559a-a3fd-11e3-8d60-70f395e25671/roslaunch-g62-26153.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://g62:50377/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud_radius
 * /cmd_vel_mux/yaml_cfg_file
 * /robot_description
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    bumper2pointcloud (nodelet/nodelet)
    cmd_vel_mux (nodelet/nodelet)
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    mobile_base_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    spawn_turtlebot_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [26171]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 5f52559a-a3fd-11e3-8d60-70f395e25671
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [26184]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [26198]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [26203]
process[spawn_turtlebot_model-4]: started with pid [26210]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5]: started with pid [26211]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.9.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.9.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

process[cmd_vel_mux-6]: started with pid [26226]
[ERROR] [1393979439.660356351]: Skipping XML Document "/opt/ros/hydro/share/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation/hector_quadrotor_pose_estimation_nodelets.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.
[ERROR] [1393979439.661284722]: Skipping XML Document "/opt/ros/hydro/share/hector_pose_estimation/hector_pose_estimation_plugins.xml" which had no Root Element.  This likely means the XML is malformed or missing.
process[bumper2pointcloud-7]: started with pid [26274]
Msg Waiting for master./opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib//libkobuki_bumper2pc_nodelet.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS7_S7_z
[FATAL] [1393979439.935531702]: Service call failed!
[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5] process has died [pid 26211, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet manager __name:=mobile_base_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/prasanna/.ros/log/5f52559a-a3fd-11e3-8d60-70f395e25671/mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5.log].
log file: /home/prasanna/.ros/log/5f52559a-a3fd-11e3-8d60-70f395e25671/mobile_base_nodelet_manager-5*.log
[ INFO] [1393979440.140029293]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1393979440.141145648]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 35.2.69.108
[bumper2pointcloud-7] process has died [pid 26274, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/nodelet/nodelet load kobuki_bumper2pc/Bumper2PcNodelet mobile_base_nodelet_manager bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud:=mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud bumper2pointcloud/core_sensors:=mobile_base/sensors/core __name:=bumper2pointcloud __log:=/home/prasanna/.ros/log/5f52559a-a3fd-11e3-8d60-70f395e25671/bumper2pointcloud-7.log].
log file: /home/prasanna/.ros/log/5f52559a-a3fd-11e3-8d60-70f395e25671/bumper2pointcloud-7*.log

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 35.2.69.108
[ INFO] [1393979441.195892088, 0.030000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
Dbg Plugin model name: mobile_base
[ INFO] [1393979443.223012821, 1.010000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
gzserver: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libgazebo_ros_kobuki.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPvNS0_6levels5LevelERKSt18basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEPKciSE_
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 26198, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver /opt/ros/hydro/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/prasanna/.ros/log/5f52559a-a3fd-11e3-8d60-70f395e25671/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/prasanna/.ros/log/5f52559a-a3fd-11e3-8d60-70f395e25671/gazebo-2*.log
[spawn_turtlebot_model-4] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/prasanna/.ros/log/5f52559a-a3fd-11e3-8d60-70f395e25671/spawn_turtlebot_model-4*.log
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 26203, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gazebo_ros/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/prasanna/.ros/log/5f52559a-a3fd-11e3-8d60-70f395e25671/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/prasanna/.ros/log/5f52559a-a3fd-11e3-8d60-70f395e25671/gazebo_gui-3*.log
```

The normal gazebo empty world works fine. Also, I am not sure why quadrotor nodelets are being referenced here.

Can someone help me please ?

Thanks,
Prasanna

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/135646/hydro-turtlebot-simulator-bringup-issues/) by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1363 on 2014-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like the same symbol error ABI breakage that's been cropping up in a few places.

Try running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

To install the latest versions of all of your ROS packages.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1